# Adobe FLA: Autoplay

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm VERY new to Flash Actionscript development and have inherited a script that starts playing a web stream when the user clicks play.

I went to the action and right clicked, Actions. This code below appeared. What I am trying to achieve is to make the stream play as soon as the object is loaded (but then obv the user should be able to click the button to stop the stream (its pay per minute)

Can anyone point me in the right direction. The code todo so might be on a trigger or something somewhere else, this is all I could find.

Edit FIXED:

```
var nc:NetConnection = null;
var nsPlay:NetStream = null;                      


var myQueryStrings=this.loaderInfo.parameters;
var user_id:String = myQueryStrings.user_id;
var site_id:String = myQueryStrings.site_id;
var stream_id:String = myQueryStrings.stream_id;
var RTMP:String = "rtmp://" + myQueryStrings.rtmp + "?" + user_id + "-" + site_id + "-" + stream_id;
var stream_query:String = stream_id + "?" + user_id + "-" + site_id + "-" + stream_id;


function ncOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent) {
   switch (infoObject.info.code) {
       case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
           _doPlay();
           break;
       case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
           trace("Unable to locate video");
        break;
   }
}


function doConnect() {
    trace("doConnect");

    // connect to the Wowza Media Server
    if (nc == null) {
        trace("nc is null");
        // create a connection to the wowza media server
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(RTMP);

        // get status information from the NetConnection object
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ncOnStatus);
        doSubscribe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, subscribe);
        doSubscribe.label = 'Stop';//Rename your btn to Stop
    } else {
        trace("nc not null");
        nsPlay = null;
        videoRemote.attachNetStream(null);
        videoRemote.clear();
        nc.close();
        nc = null;
        prompt.text = "";
    }
}



function nsPlayOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent) {
    trace("nsPlay: "+infoObject.info.code+" ("+infoObject.info.description+")");
    if (infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" || infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Failed")
        prompt.text = infoObject.info.description;
}


function subscribe(event:MouseEvent) {
    trace("subscribe");

    if (doSubscribe.label == 'Play') {
        _doPlay();//moved code into a method so you can call it on load
    } else {       
        // here we are shutting down the connection to the server
        videoRemote.attachNetStream(null);
        nsPlay.play(null);
        nsPlay.close();

        doSubscribe.label = 'Play';
    }
}


function nsPublishOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent) {
    trace("nsPublish: "+infoObject.info.code+" ("+infoObject.info.description+")");
    if (infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" || infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Failed")
        prompt.text = infoObject.info.description;
}


function _doPlay():void {
    // create a new NetStream object for video playback
        trace("do play");
        trace(nc);
        nsPlay = new NetStream(nc);

        // trace the NetStream status information
        nsPlay.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, nsPlayOnStatus);

        var nsPlayClientObj:Object = new Object();
        nsPlay.client = nsPlayClientObj;
        nsPlayClientObj.onMetaData = function(infoObject:Object) 
        {
            trace("onMetaData");

            // print debug information about the metaData
            for (var propName:String in infoObject)
            {
                trace("  "+propName + " = " + infoObject[propName]);

                if (propName == "CameraWidth") { videoRemote.width = infoObject["CameraWidth"]; }
                if (propName == "CameraHeight") { videoRemote.height = infoObject["CameraHeight"]; }
            }
        };      

        // set the buffer time to zero since it is chat
        nsPlay.bufferTime = 0;

        // subscribe to the named stream
        nsPlay.play(stream_query);

        //prompt.text = stream_query;

        // attach to the stream
        videoRemote.attachNetStream(nsPlay);

        doSubscribe.label = 'Stop';
}


stage.align = "TL";
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";


doConnect();
stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var nc:NetConnection = null;
var nsPlay:NetStream = null;                      

//get var from flash page
var myQueryStrings=this.loaderInfo.parameters;
var user_id:String = myQueryStrings.user_id;
var site_id:String = myQueryStrings.site_id;
var stream_id:String = myQueryStrings.stream_id;
var RTMP:String = "rtmp://" + myQueryStrings.rtmp + "?" + user_id + "-" + site_id + "-" + stream_id;
var stream_query:String = stream_id + "?" + user_id + "-" + site_id + "-" + stream_id;

function ncOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent)
{
    trace("nc: "+infoObject.info.code+" ("+infoObject.info.description+")");
    if (infoObject.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Failed")
        prompt.text = "Connection failed: please refresh the page and try again";
    else if (infoObject.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected")
        prompt.text = infoObject.info.description;
}

function doConnect()
{
    // connect to the Wowza Media Server
    if (nc == null)
    {
        // create a connection to the wowza media server
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(RTMP);

        // get status information from the NetConnection object
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ncOnStatus);

        doSubscribe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, subscribe);
        //doSubscribe.label = 'Play';
        doSubscribe.label = 'Stop';//Rename your btn to Stop
        _doPlay();//fire the video
        //prompt.text = RTMP;
    }
    else
    {
        nsPlay = null;

        videoRemote.attachNetStream(null);
        videoRemote.clear();

        nc.close();
        nc = null;

        prompt.text = "";
    }
}



function nsPlayOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent)
{
    trace("nsPlay: "+infoObject.info.code+" ("+infoObject.info.description+")");
    if (infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" || infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Failed")
        prompt.text = infoObject.info.description;
}

function subscribe(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if (doSubscribe.label == 'Play')
    {
        _doPlay();//moved code into a method so you can call it on load
    }
    else
    {       
        // here we are shutting down the connection to the server
        videoRemote.attachNetStream(null);
        nsPlay.play(null);
        nsPlay.close();

        doSubscribe.label = 'Play';
    }
}

function nsPublishOnStatus(infoObject:NetStatusEvent)
{
    trace("nsPublish: "+infoObject.info.code+" ("+infoObject.info.description+")");
    if (infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" || infoObject.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Failed")
        prompt.text = infoObject.info.description;
}

function _doPlay():void {
    // create a new NetStream object for video playback
        nsPlay = new NetStream(nc);

        // trace the NetStream status information
        nsPlay.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, nsPlayOnStatus);

        var nsPlayClientObj:Object = new Object();
        nsPlay.client = nsPlayClientObj;
        nsPlayClientObj.onMetaData = function(infoObject:Object) 
        {
            trace("onMetaData");

            // print debug information about the metaData
            for (var propName:String in infoObject)
            {
                trace("  "+propName + " = " + infoObject[propName]);

                if (propName == "CameraWidth") { videoRemote.width = infoObject["CameraWidth"]; }
                if (propName == "CameraHeight") { videoRemote.height = infoObject["CameraHeight"]; }
            }
        };      

        // set the buffer time to zero since it is chat
        nsPlay.bufferTime = 0;

        // subscribe to the named stream
        nsPlay.play(stream_query);

        //prompt.text = stream_query;

        // attach to the stream
        videoRemote.attachNetStream(nsPlay);

        doSubscribe.label = 'Stop';
}

stage.align = "TL";
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";

doConnect();
stop();
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the webcam doesn't show up, however the button says "Stop" so it got that far.

I'm unsure how I'd debug why this isnt working, do you have any advice?

Comment: Okay I managed to get it working, I had to make sure it didnt trigger _onPlay before the connection. Many thanks for your help.